# Get current volume of device sound output - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, volume

I am playing a song in the background of my app (with `AVAudioPlayer`) and I want to have some bars bouncing up and down similar to in Garageband where you set a track's volume. I want to know how to get the current volume of the song playing, not the volume the device is set at.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about metering, not volume. See the docs for [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067). You need to use the various APIs for metering such as `meteringEnabled` and `averagePowerForChannel:`.

Apple provides a sample app that demonstrates this. See the [avTouch sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636).

And you can find plenty of discussions here on Stack Overflow. See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=avaudioplayer%20metering).